# Django Display latest emails to certain user in Template

Tags: python, django, email, notifications

My django app I have created relies heavily on emails that are sent like this:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Lets say that I keep sending an email to an user's email like this:

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
post_title = post.title
author_of_post = post.author
post_email = author_of_post.email
send_mail(
    'An User Comment on Your Post',
    '''Dear User, ''' '''
                    Your post, ''' + post_title + ''' was comment on by an user. Want to reply and check it out?
                --From the People at Site'''
                ,
                'randomemailuser@domain.com',
                [post_email],
)
```

Now I want to add a notifications area, where it will display all the latest emails sent to the user, in the example of above `post_email`. So how would I do this. To sum up, I want to have a template where an user can see the latest emails sent to their account, sort of like a notification area. Thanks.

Comment: Keep them stored in your database and present the data to user in a template using a separate API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep track of the emails that you are sending, you will need to save this information in your database, which means introducing a model. Something like this should do the trick:

```
#models.py

class SentEmail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...
```

You can obviously attach any additional info onto this model that you want (time sent, email body etc.). Then when you send an email, you'll also want to save a model instance, e.g:

```
from .models import SentEmail


...

send_mail( ... ) # all the stuff you had before
SentEmail.objects.create(
    email_subject="An User Comment on Your Post"
    user=whoever_the_user_is
)
```

Then you just create a view and template to display this information the same way you would any other view.

#### An alternative approach

Some third party services allow you to manage all transactional emails (sendgrid, mailgun etc.), and they may provide an API for you to fetch all emails sent to a particular user. This would allow you to achieve the kind of thing you described above, but to be honest, I think the approach I suggested above would be alot simpler.